# Python 'Dictionary changed size during iteration' error even though size changes after iterations should be complete

Tags: python, dictionary, size, iteration

I have a list of cities and I am trying to group them together based on distance.  I am iterating through the list of cities.  The first city in the list has nothing to compare to, so it automatically creates its own city group.  The subsequent cities in the list are compared to all of the cities in the existing groups of cities.  If the city is within a threshold distance of any of the cities in a city group, it is added to the city group.  Otherwise, it creates a new group.  My groups are being stored as dictionaries with one dictionary storing the city groups and then for each city group there is a dictionary storing all of the cities in that group.

I am calling findsetlist() where it checks to see if the city should belong to an existing city group or create a new one.  After the calling of findsetlist(), I then update the city group dictionary with either the addition of the city to an existing group or the creation of the new group.  When I run the code, I am getting an error that says "dictionary changed size during iteration".  It is saying that I am changing the size of my dictionary while it is iterating inside of my 'for loops'.  But I don't change the size until after it should have exited both 'for loops', so I don't understand why it is having a problem.

I appreciate any help that you can give me.  Thank you.

```
class citySets:  
    def __init__(self,city,citysetdict,citysetnum):  
        self.city=city  
        self.citysetdict=citysetdict  
        self.citysetnum=citysetnum  
    def findsetlists(self):  
        if len (self.citysetdict)==0:  
            self.citysetnum=1  
            self.closecitysetnum=1  
            self.closeval=9999999999  
            self.temp={}  
            self.temp[self.city[apiad]]=self.city  
        else:  
            self.closecitysetnum=self.citysetnum+1  
            self.closeval=9999999999  
            self.temp={}  
            for self.key in self.citysetdict:  
                for self.key2 in self.citysetdict[self.key]:  
                    self.secondcity= self.citysetdict[self.key][self.key2]  
                    self.compare=cityCompare(self.city,self.secondcity)  
                    self.compare.distance()  
                    if self.compare.dist<=distancethreshold:  
                        self.closecitysetnum=self.key  
                        self.temp = self.citysetdict[self.key]  
                        self.temp[self.city[apiad]]=self.city  

citysets={}  
for currentcity in citylist:  
    d=citySets(currentcity,citysets,citysetnum)  
    d.findsetlists()  
    citysetnum=d.closecitysetnum  
    citysets[citysetnum]=d.temp
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of funny-looking stuff in here that it would help if you would clear up. What is `city` expected to be? What is `apiad`? Why are you trying to use attributes (e.g., `self.key`) as a loop variable?

Comment: `for self.key in self.citysetdict:`. Oh Gosh... Why don't you use `for key in self.citysetdict`? Why create a new instance attribute just for an iteration?

Comment: City is expected to be a list and apiad is the address of the city name within that list.  So I am trying to use the name of the city as a key within the city group.  In answer to your other question, I am very new to object oriented programming and I haven't quite figured out when I need the 'self.' in front of a variable, so I have been adding it to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            ...
            for self.key2 in self.citysetdict[self.key]:
                 ....
                 if self.compare.dist<=distancethreshold: 
                    ...
                    self.temp = self.citysetdict[self.key]
                    self.temp[self.city[apiad]]=self.city
```

This looks like your problem. You're iterating over the dictionary `self.citysetdict[self.key]`. Then you assign `self.citysetdict[self.key]` to `self.temp`, and then assign an item of `self.temp` (which will change its size unless the key already existed).

As an aside, when Python reported that error about "dictionary size changed during iteration", **it would have told you exactly which line was the problem**. That clue could have saved your confusion about how you thought you weren't changing size until after the for loops were finished, because it would clearly have pointed to a line within the for loops (which also greatly narrows down which dictionary is the problem). But even if you don't yet know how to read the stack traces printed in the error message to do this kind of problem identification (which is fine, everyone has to learn sometime), when you're asking others for help please *include the error message*, so that the people helping you can make use of this clue!

Comment: Sorry for not including the error message in full 'for self.key2 in self.wellsetdict[self.key]:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration'    Thank you for the answer and for the lesson in posting etiquette.  This is my first time posting.  I will try and do better with future posts.

Comment: @user3402834 Ah, I don't see `wellsetdict` anywhere in the code you've posted, so my guess might not actually be your problem.

Comment: I apologize, I had changed a variable name before running and getting the error message.  Should be:'for key2 in self.citysetdict[key]:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration'.  I have tried adding 'citysets[self.closecitysetnum]=self.temp with the same indent as the 'if' and 'else' statements at the end of findcitylist(). I still get the same error. Both for loops have already passed before I make the assignment, how does the assignment feed back in to the for loops?  Is there a way to exit after I make the assignment of self.temp so that it can't feed back into the for loops?

Comment: @user3402834 Why do you think it's an assignment after the for loops that's causing your issue? I don't think the problem is occurring after the for loops, so it won't matter what you put there. The potential problem I have spotted in your code is that you are assigning `temp` to refer to the dictionary you're iterating over, and then assigning an item inside `temp`, within the for loops; if that really is a problem, it would cause the exception you're seeing.

Comment: @user3402834 Great! Glad you could fix your problem.